# Installation of private npm package from CodeArtifact fails with "401 Unauthorized" with yarn and yarn.lock

Tags: yarnpkg, npm-package, lockfile, aws-codeartifact

We have a private npm package in CodeArtifact that we want to install as part of our `package.json`.

We are using Yarn as a package manager and have a `yarn.lock` file to control the versions.
When trying to install with `yarn install --frozen-lockfile` it's failing on the installation of the private package with `Request failed \"401 Unauthorized\`.

When using npm it's working fine. But we want to stick with yarn.
Anybody experienced the same issue?

Comment: Yarn uses NPM behind the scenes. Does `~/.npmrc` contain the configuration for the repository and the auth token?

Answer (score 0):

3 Possible reasons could be:

1. You've cached the version of the package, npm using the cached version while you run `npm i`, you can clear the cache data using the below command.

```bash
npm cache clean --force
```

2. Expired codeartifact credentials, you can update them using the below command.

```bash
CODEARTIFACT_DOMAIN=<your codeartifact domain>
CODEARTIFACT_REPO=<your codeartifact repo>
NAMESPACE=<your package namespace>

# Get AWS account ID
AWS_ACCOUNT_ID=$(aws sts get-caller-identity --query 'Account' --output text)

# Get CodeArtifact authorization token and endpoint
CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN=$(aws codeartifact get-authorization-token --domain $CODEARTIFACT_DOMAIN --query authorizationToken --output text)
CODEARTIFACT_ENDPOINT=$(aws codeartifact get-repository-endpoint --domain $CODEARTIFACT_DOMAIN --repository $CODEARTIFACT_REPO --format npm)

# Set default registry back to npmjs.org
npm config set registry=https://registry.npmjs.org

# Set authentication token and always-auth option for CodeArtifact repository
npm config set //$CODEARTIFACT_DOMAIN-$AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.d.codeartifact.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/npm/$CODEARTIFACT_REPO/:_authToken=$CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN
npm config set //$CODEARTIFACT_DOMAIN-$AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.d.codeartifact.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/npm/$CODEARTIFACT_REPO/:always-auth=true

# Namespace-specific config
npm config set @$NAMESPACE:registry https://$CODEARTIFACT_DOMAIN-$AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.d.codeartifact.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/npm/$CODEARTIFACT_REPO/
```

3. Improper `yarn.lock`, this might contain the resolved URL with the expired auth token, you can remove the `yarn.lock` and regenerate it by running `yarn`

And if you're using yarn v2, then look into [this answer](https://repost.aws/questions/QUS_4wm6xrT1C_bdVBihr6Rw/yarn-fails-to-install-from-code-artifact)

Answer (score 0):

> Please ensure you have already `aws codeartifact login`.

According to [Configure and use Yarn with CodeArtifact](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codeartifact/latest/ug/npm-yarn.html):

- "For npm 7.X and 8.X, you must add `always-auth=true` to your `~/.npmrc` file to use Yarn".

If you don't wanna bother with manually editing `~/.npmrc`, then you can simply:

- `npm config set always-auth true`

In Github Actions, we can even:

```yaml
- uses: actions/setup-node@v3
  with:
    node-version: 18
    always-auth: 'true' // Easy!
```